# How do I mark emails as read in notmuch?

Tags: email, notmuch

This feels like a super basic question, but it's got me stumped. I'm using `mbsync` + `notmuch` to collect my email locally, both from a Google mail account in one case and from an Exchange account in another. I can read my email just fine in `notmuch-mode` but... the messages are never marked as "read" -- they're still tagged as unread no matter what I do.

I'm not doing anything particularly interesting in the configuration of either of those tools, that I know of, but I'll be honest I'm completely new to the idea of even reading email in Emacs; I'm dipping my toes in the water and finding that the water is deep and confusing :)

So, how do I mark emails as "read" in `notmuch-mode` in a way that will propagate back to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the variable `notmuch-show-mark-read-function` to control this. The default value is `notmuch-show-seen-current-message`, which does mark the message as read.